# Client can't access Server (VM to VM interaction), Ping ok, SSH ok

Tags: c, linux, ssh, tcp, virtual-machine

I currently do experiments the interation between vm using CentOS. I wanna know about TCP interation using Client and Server socket C programming. I have two VM(s) which have 'vm_A' and 'vm_B' as their's hostname.

From vm_A I tried to connect vm_B using ssh and it was connected, as well as ping each other. However, when I tried to run ./echoserver on vm_A and ./echoclient [ip vm_A] on vm_B that remotely accessed using ssh by vm_A. It keeps saying  'Problem in connecting to the server: No route to host'

I have tried with the hostname@ip vm_A  but it still returns error.

Here are the code for echoserver.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define MAXLINE 4096 /*max text line length*/
#define SERV_PORT 3000 /*port*/
#define LISTENQ 8 /*maximum number of client connections*/

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
 int listenfd, connfd, n;
 pid_t childpid;
 socklen_t clilen;
 char buf[MAXLINE];
 struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;

 //Create a socket for the soclet
 //If sockfd<0 there was an error in the creation of the socket
 if ((listenfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) <0) {
  perror("Problem in creating the socket");
  exit(2);
 }


 //preparation of the socket address
 servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
 servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

 //bind the socket
 bind (listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

 //listen to the socket by creating a connection queue, then wait for clients
 listen (listenfd, LISTENQ);

 printf("%s\n","Server running...waiting for connections.");

 for ( ; ; ) {

  clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
  //accept a connection
  connfd = accept (listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &clilen);

  printf("%s\n","Received request...");

  if ( (childpid = fork ()) == 0 ) {//if it?s 0, it?s child process

    printf ("%s\n","Child created for dealing with client requests");

    //close listening socket
    close (listenfd);

    while ( (n = recv(connfd, buf, MAXLINE,0)) > 0)  {
     printf("%s","String received from and resent to the client:");
     puts(buf);
     send(connfd, buf, n, 0);
    }

    if (n < 0)
      printf("%s\n", "Read error");
    exit(0);
  }
  //close socket of the server
  close(connfd);
 }
}
```

Here are the code for echoclient.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


#define MAXLINE 4096 /*max text line length*/
#define SERV_PORT 3000 /*port*/

int
main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
 int sockfd;
 struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
 char sendline[MAXLINE], recvline[MAXLINE];

 //basic check of the arguments
 //additional checks can be inserted
 if (argc !=2) {
  perror("Usage: TCPClient <IP address of the server"); 
  exit(1);
 }

 //Create a socket for the client
 //If sockfd<0 there was an error in the creation of the socket
 if ((sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) <0) {
  perror("Problem in creating the socket");
  exit(2);
 }

 //Creation of the socket
 memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
 servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr(argv[1]);
 servaddr.sin_port =  htons(SERV_PORT); //convert to big-endian order

 //Connection of the client to the socket 
 if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))<0) {
  perror("Problem in connecting to the server");
  exit(3);
 }

 while (fgets(sendline, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL) {

  send(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline), 0);

  if (recv(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE,0) == 0){
   //error: server terminated prematurely
   perror("The server terminated prematurely"); 
   exit(4);
  }
  printf("%s", "String received from the server: ");
  fputs(recvline, stdout);
 }

 exit(0);
}
```

Do you have any suggestions for me to fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If ping to ip is ok, probably you need to check if serevr port is accessible from client by doing telnet from client to server IP port,

Comment: @Pras I used SSH.. I guess its similar to telnet?

Comment: SSH will connect to default port 22 unless its configured on diffrent port, you would want to check if 3000  is accessble or not so from client you should try "telnet serverIP 3000"

Comment: @Pras I can access SSH but for my client and server program, cant connect each other.